# In Elasticsearch how do I get an average of time differences of documents for a specific user?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say a single Elasticsearch document may look like this:

```
{
    "created": "2018-11-26T22:20:01+00:00",
    "user_id": 2,
    "text": "Test!"
    "verb": "comment_posted",
    "thread_id": 1
}
```

I would like to filter by verb to only "comment_posted", then get the average time between comments for a specific post (created field) for each user.

Here's an example dataset and expected results:

- User 'A' posts on thread '1' (starting the thread) at 1:30
- User 'B' posts on thread '2' (starting the thread) at 1:45
- User 'A' posts on thread '2' at 2:00
- User 'B' posts on thread '1' at 3:30
- User 'B' posts on thread '1' at 4:30
- User 'A' posts on thread '1' at 5:15

User 'A' would have an average of 30 minutes (2:00 - 1:45 and 5:15 - 4:30), and user 'B' would have an average of 120 minutes (3:30 - 1:30 and 4:30 - 3:30).

What would my query look like?

Comment: Welcome to SO!
The times in your second-to-last last paragraph don't match with any time mentioned before, it makes it a little harder to understand the result you want.

Comment: @Adr Thank you for pointing that out. i've corrected the times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

It's potentially *possible* to do this but not *recommended*.

**Long answer**

In general to do something like this you'd need to use an [aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html).

The only aggregation that allows computing deltas is the [Serial Differencing Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-serialdiff-aggregation.html). However, it's meant to be used in the context of a histogram or date histogram aggregation.

In your case, to get a single comment per histogram bucket you could create a histogram with very small bucket (e.g. a subdivision of a second), then use serial differencing to get the time deltas.
As mentioned in [this answer](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/calculate-the-time-difference-between-consecutive-documents/128282/11) on the ElasticSearch forum however, this would be terrible performance-wise.

So the answer here is that you need to compute those deltas at index-time, or using data from another store if you have one (this would be very easy to compute in Postgres for example).

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I thought this might be a bit too much for aggregations but I wasn't sure if I was just missing some obvious functionality I didn't know about. Would it make sense to create another document containing this information, or are you suggesting attaching this info to the new/existing document? I suppose the answer to this question is up to me and my own decision for implementation, but what would you do given the information provided?

Comment: @AaronCheever it's hard to tell without knowing more - I'd question the need to put this data in ElasticSearch in the first place. ES is meant for search, and it seems the kind of search you can do on time delta is quite limited, so you don't need ES for that.

Comment: In the end the requirements changed so I didn't need to come up with a solution. Making another document or creating that data at index time seem like the best solution if I were to still need to do this.